# HTML Button created in object constructors onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, dom

So whatever is causing the error must actually be in this loop:
Creating a box by calling the gridBox constructor on its own works. But those created by the buildField function do not return an on click event.

```
var grid = [];
function buildField(size){
    //loops through each row
    for(var y=0; y<size;y++){
        //loops through each column
        grid[y]=[];
        for(var x=0; x<size; x++){
            //create new object for grid
            grid[y][x] = new gridBox(x,y); 
        }
        document.getElementById("board").innerHTML += "<br>";
    }
}

function gridBox(x,y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    var me = this;
    //function to create and add button.
    function makeBtn(){
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.type = "BUTTON";
        btn.className = "gridButton";
        btn.value = "BUTTON";
        btn.name = me;
        btn.onclick = function(){
            console.log("click");
        };
        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(btn);
        console.log("madeButton");
    }
    makeBtn();
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting up the `onclick` property, have you tried adding the callback via `btn.addEventListener()`?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vihuwis/1/edit?html,js,output — works fine when I test it.

Comment: There's sufficient code there to understand the problem, but you really should create proper a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> document.getElementById("board").innerHTML += "<br>";
> ```

This will:

1. Convert the DOM to HTML
2. Add `<br>` to that HTML
3. Convert that HTML to DOM
4. Overwrite the existing DOM with that

… the `onclick` event handlers will not be part of the serialised HTML, so they will be lost when step 4 happens.

Use `createElement` and `appendChild` again. Don't use `innerHTML`.

Comment: That fixed it thank you! I will be more careful using innerHTML in the future.

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me:

```js
function gridBox(x,y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    var me = this;
    //function to create and add button.
    function makeBtn(){
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.className = "gridButton";
        btn.textContent = "Click Me";
        btn.name = me;
        btn.onclick = function(){
            console.log("click");
        };
        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(btn);
        console.log("madeButton");
    }
    makeBtn();
}

gridBox(10,10);
```

```css
.gridButton {
  height:30px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id=board></div>
```

Comment: A down vote less than a second after posting? Really?

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem, say so in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Quentin First, you can't possibly have read my answer before down voting it because it was instantaneous. Second, I am showing code that does what the OP is attempting, proving that the problem isn't with this code and therefore removing this from suspicion. Process of elimination is a perfectly valid form of problem solving.

Comment: "First, you can't possibly have read my answer before down voting it because it was instantaneous" — I could tell that it didn't solve the problem (because there is no problem) without looking at it. I could tell at a glance you hadn't included an explanation of how it fixed the problem (which it can't do anyway since there isn't a problem).

Comment: "Process of elimination is a perfectly valid form of problem solving." — Eliminating the problem as being with the code in the question is all very well, but it doesn't solve their problem, so it shouldn't be an answer.

Answer (score -1):

try adding `btn.onClick` after document...appendChild(..) :
this works for me

```js
function gridBox(x,y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    var me = this;
    //function to create and add button.
    function makeBtn(){
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.type = "BUTTON";
        btn.className = "gridButton";
        btn.value = "BUTTON";
        btn.name = me;
        document.getElementById("board").appendChild(btn);
        btn.onclick = function(){
            console.log("click");
        };
        console.log("madeButton");
    }
    makeBtn();
}
// make simple button
gridBox(10,10);
```

```html
<div id="board">
  
</div>
```

Comment: `onClick` won't work, the property is called `onclick` and JavaScript is case sensitive. Moving it after appending won't make a difference either since the code in the question works with it in its original position.

Comment: @Aryanio — The existing code works. jQuery will just bloat things.

Answer (score -2):

Try with:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ });
```

instead of your btn.onclick

Comment: Why should that fix it?